# In which case should each JavaFX update method be used?

Tags: java, performance, javafx, javafx-8

There are, as far as I know, 3 ways to update a JavaFX element:

- `Platform.runLater();`
- `Task`
- `Timeline`

In my specific case, I receive data every 750-1000ms and all I am doing in JavaFX is updating an LineChart every 1000ms. Every 1000ms, I call this method:

```
mySeries.getData().add(myIndex,myNewDoubleValue);
```

I have no performance problems regarding the "logic" of the software, everything runs on time and only uses 0-1% of the CPU when the window is minimized.

The problem comes when I am showing the interface window on screen while updating it every second, I am getting 30-45% constant CPU usage (This is a problem as my software is not the only one running on the PC, and I need to consume as little resources as possible).

This is my latest attempt:

```
Timeline refreshChart = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        mySeries.getData().add(myIndex,myNewDoubleValue);
    }
}), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
refreshCharts.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
refreshCharts.play();
```

I have tried using a while() loop with Platform.runLater() to update every second and I have also tried using Tasks (JavaFX Task class), all of them show similar performance (Little CPU usage when minimized, but HUGE CPU usage when actually showing the interface).

*Note:* I also set the charts to not be animated, as I thought this was the problem, it helped, but didn't really fix anything:

```
myChart.setAnimated(false);
```

What method should I be using? Am I missing something? How can I lower the CPU usage?

**Update:** I executed the software using `` and this was the information that it printed:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 es1 sw j2d
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es1.ES1Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es1.ES1Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es1.ES1Pipeline
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
     vsync: true vpipe: false
```

Comment: What OS version do you use? Is the graphic card (driver) supported or are you using software rendering? (run with -Djavafx.verbose=true to get more information)

Comment: I am using 64bits W10. I don't know if the driver is supported or if I am running software rendering, I run the program with -Djavafx.verbose=true and I'll update the question with the information that was printed.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am currently using the integrated `Intel(R) HD Graphics 530` GPU. I already updated the post with the log information.

Comment: It's definitely using software rendering, for some reason it won't let me use hardware rendering (I've got a pretty recent driver, but I will update that and DirectX right now, and test again).

Comment: What Java version do you have? Could something have gone wrong with the Java installation? It seems like it can't find some core Java classes (`com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline`). Maybe try updating/reinstalling Java?